# Acessar na view os últimos valores inseridos no banco de dados

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando acessar os últimos "books" inseridos no banco, e exibir na view.

Essa função do controller retorna a view com os valores recuperados do banco.

```
public function index(){
        $books = Book::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5);
        return view('index')->with('books', $books);
    }
```

Na view está assim:

```
@foreach($books as $book)
        {{$book->name}}
@endforeach
```

Porém nada é exibido (há dados no banco), usando `{{dd($books)}}` tenho isso como retorno:

```
Builder {#180 ▼
  #query: Builder {#179 ▶}
  #model: Book {#168 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: []
  #macros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:11 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}
```

Não consigo entender por que o foreach não está exibindo os valores, já que o dd() mostra que o objeto foi passado. Como posso acessar corretamente os valores dos últimos 5 books?

Comment: tente passar os dados para a view desta maneira; `return view('index', ['books' => $books]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou por fim um `get();` para retornar os dados dessa coleção ([`Collections`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections)). O erro é que esta sendo enviando para [`view`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views) um objeto [`Builder`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) ([`object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries)).

***Código***

```
public function index()
{
    $books = Book::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
    return view('index')->with('books', $books);
}
```

Comment: A nível de curiosidade, qual a utilidade de um objeto Builder?

Comment: O objeto `Builder` seria a construção das suas ***consultas***, colocando `where`, `join`, `orderBy`, `limit`, etc, mas, ela precisa ter um fim (ou um finalizador) para trazer resultados que pode ser `get()`, `first()` etc ...